# Архитектура программы

Tags: java, архитектура, swing

Здравствуйте.

Поставили задачу написать программу - систему учета сведения о пользователях некоторой информационной системы. Использовать можно только Swing для интерфейса и стандартную Java. Также необходимо реализовать изменение статуса пользователей и учет активности пользователей. Я никак не могу придумать устройство программы. Пока что:

1. Есть классы User (абстрактный), и далее его расширяют SimpleUser, администратор, модератор и т.д. Но не знаю, как реализовать различные права.
2. Есть класс Engine, управляющий UI, обрабатывающий запросы от пользователей.
3. Класс UI. Можно заходить в определённого пользователя (без логина-пароля) и взаимодействовать с системой.

Как реализовать различные права? Где хранить пользователей? Как вести учёт активности, к примеру? Как сделать "вход" в пользователя?
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Как-то странно. Иерархия User->SimpleUser,Admin... не понятна. У вас при перещелкивании какой-то галки объекты пересоздаются? Т.е. был простой юзер, стал админ, вы объект юзера пересоздали?

На самом деле права реализуются через группы. Юзер входит в группу, значит что-то может. Если у вас группы предполагаются зашитыми жестко, значит надо создавать иерархию групп (хотя на самом деле там не иерархия, а множество), а не юзеров. В общем случае группа - это фактически совокупность прав для юзеров, входящих в группу. Права - это глобальный список возможных действий, возможных видов отображения интерфейса и т.д. Если юзер входит в несколько групп, права складываются бинарно через дизъюнкцию (or).

Например.

Вася входит в группу "SimpleUsers" и в группу "Admins".
Группа "SimpleUsers" содержит права на вход в UI без пароля.
Группа "Admins" содержит права на вход в админку по паролю. А также в UI отображается кнопка "Admin section".

ЗЫ Бывают варианты с приоритетом, когда сложение выполняется сложнее (через конъюнкцию или через отрицание). Типа модератор не может портить раздел, в котором он не хозяин. В БД это может быть реализовано через RLS (row level security).

Comment: Я бы тоже хотел использовать БД, но в задании поставили рамки. За идею с группами - большое спасибо, как-то сам не додумался. Но получается, если группы не будут являться именно коллекциями со списком прав(предполагаю просто boolean переменные), права пользователей нельзя будет изменить? То есть например не получится сделать это через интерфейсы? И будет ли лишним нагромождением создание классов - групп с массивом пользователей, входящих в него внутри и списком прав?

Comment: С правами интерфейсы и прочие прелести ООП с наследованиями и проч не помогут. Все верно должна быть гибкость в настройках прав, поэтому информацию о правах групп надо где-то хранить. Если правильно понимаю, то без БД, вам придется мучиться с файлами, в которых хранится информация, в том числе об "учете сведений о пользователях". В таком случае можно взять sqlite базу, которая не требует выделенного сервера, и так сказать расширить рамки техзадания :)